# Swift 3 equivalent for Java property with type that implements specific interface

Tags: java, swift, interface, protocols

Please help translate following Java code into Swift 3:

```
interface A {
}

class BiA implements A {
}

interface C {
    List<? extends A> getAs();
}

class D implements C {
    List<BiA> getAs();
}
```

TIA

Comment: I really, really want to post and answer, but code requests are not encouraged on SO, you'll need to make a further attempt and provide us with more information about what problems you're having.  Hint `interface` ~= `protocol`

Comment: Sure, the problem I'm facing is with protocol C. I don't know how to declare the protocol, I don't know how to represent "? extends A" in Swift. I'm happy to use built-in Swift arrays. All I want is to be able to use class BiA in D where the getAs() implements the interface/protocol method from C. It's odd that such a simple construct is so hard to get an answer for, not in any Apple guides nor in any forums.

Comment: Honestly, Swift's generic support isn't as good as Java's (some people will hate me for that, but it's just not as powerful).  With `C`, you want do some research into `associatedtype`, now once you start down this road, you will discover many pitfalls with it (IMHO) as Swifts type system is very pragmatic

Comment: Unfortunately a Swift newbie, would @MadProgrammer be able to elaborate?

Comment: [A Swift Look at Protocols with Associated Types](https://www.natashatherobot.com/swift-protocols-with-associated-types/), [Swift: What are Protocols with Associated Types?](https://www.natashatherobot.com/swift-what-are-protocols-with-associated-types/), [Swift: Associated Types](http://www.russbishop.net/swift-associated-types)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
protocol A {
    func hello()
}

class BiA: A {
    func hello() {
        print("Hello")
    }
}

class B2iA: A {
    func hello() {
        print("Hello2")
    }
}

protocol C {
    associatedtype Someclass
    func getAs() -> [Someclass]
}

class D: C {
    typealias Someclass = A
    func getAs() -> [Someclass] {
        return [BiA(), B2iA()]
    }
}

D().getAs().forEach({  $0.hello() })
```

**Result:**

Hello

Hello2